# how to pass a variable array/object to python (google app engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

As an example, I understand that a POST of `html://www.test.com/?color=red` can be retrieved by

```
color=self.request.get('color')
#print color would output red
```

Instead, I am trying to get something like `html://www.test.com/?colors=red,orange,yellow,green,blue,violet` such that

```
colors=self.request.get('colors')
for color in colors:
  #the first loop color=red
  #the second loop color=orange
  #and so on
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is a standard for this. You can send comma separated string (as is your example) and if you can "decode" it on your server side - that's OK. Or you can simply use JSON.

Comment: you can also use multiple element with the same name and call self.request.get_all which will give you back a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple case you can just use:

```
for color in colors.split(","):
    # the first loop color=red
    # the second loop color=orange
    # and so on
```